# How do I automatically add cc addresses in a replying email?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

When I get an email, the CC field has email addresses so everyone who's email addresses are there get emailed as well. When I reply I want the same addresses in the CC field so that the same people will get the message I sent in reply to the person who originally sent the message.

Is there a way to quickly do this in Microsoft Outlook 2010 without having to add the addresses in myself (because a lot of the time I may forget an address)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the option you are looking for is "Reply to All" instead of simply "Reply". It should keep everyone from the TO an CC in the reply.

Comment: i've always thought "Replly to All" just did To and From Addresses, not CC, thanks for your help

Comment: Adding to this, `Ctrl-R` will "Reply" to the open message and `Ctrl-Shift-R` will "Reply-All"